# How to put parentheses for multiline text in r markdown?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Could anybody help me to overcome this?
I've tried several ways but it still didnt't work.
I wanna put big parentheses for these three line texts like the image below but I couldn't do it.

`$$\left( total\ akumulasi\ zat\ kimia\ i\\ dalam\ elemen\ volume\\ selama\ selang\ waktu\ \Delta x \right)$$`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: can you provide a MWE and yours previous attempts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `$$`, but `\[ ... \]`. And put the multiline text in a `tabular`.

```
\[
  \left(
    \begin{tabular}{c}
      total\ akumulasi\ zat\ kimia\ i\\ dalam\ elemen\ volume\\ selama\ selang\ waktu\ \Delta x
    \end{tabular}
  \right)
\]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, Sir. But i dont know somehow it still didn't work on my r markdown file. Are there any another possible ways? Or should i use some packages? @PietervanOostrum